# AVAudioEngine track progress of audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio

I've setup my audio engine and connected a few nodes, so as to make an audio graph that looks like this:

```
//
//AVAudioPlayerNode --> AVAudioMixerNode --> AVAudioUnitVarispeed ---> AvAudioOutputNode
//       |                                                         |
// AVAudioPCMBuffer                                             AudioTap
//
```

Everything is working and the audio engine is running. Now I would like to get the framePosition (progress, consumed frames, %) of the AVAudioPlayerNode/AVAudioPCMBuffer so as to update the current position in my UI. Something like:

```
[timeEffectNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:4096 format:[timeEffectNode outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when) {
    //calculate the current node progress here. ???
}];
```

I'm certain there has to be a way of doing this but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to achieve this?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply take a snapshot of your current node time with

```
AVAudioTime *now = player.lastRenderTime;
```

and then ask your player

```
[player playerTimeForNodeTime:now];
```

Of course you can do this in one call

```
[player playerTimeForNodeTime:player.lastRenderTime];
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a player that works with AVAudioEngine and AVPCMBufferNode. The player keeps an internal time of total time that the player has been playing. To access it you must get the players lastRenderTime and then use the (sampleTime / sampleRate). This should return total time the player has been playing in seconds.

If you want to reset the players timer (like when you seek through a file or switch to new song) you must set use the player's playAtTime method. The playAtTime does not perform any file seeking, it just modifies the players internal timer and then starts playback.

I hope this helps.

If you'd like a reference as to how I used this, check out my project: https://github.com/danielmj/AEAudioPlayer

Comment: I am afraid there is some confusion going on here! You definitely can't seek/change a player's internal time position. With ***player playAtTime:*** you define the start position for its first start on the engine. Every subsequent start will continue from the last paused position of the player. You can of course shift every single subsequent start to any place in the future too - but you cannot randomly access a time position in your player!!! The only thing you can do is stopping your player! That way its start position gets reset to 0 and it gets rid of all scheduled file/segments/buffers...

Comment: If you really want to access a certain position of your audio file you will have to schedule a ***segment*** on the player and assign your chosen start time to the segments ***atTime:*** parameter... - This pins your requested start time to player time 0. So doing this randomly on the go means essentially - 1) reset your player to start time 0 by stopping it - 2) calculate a new start position within the audio file - 3) schedule a new segment onto the empty player with this newly calculated start position - 4) start the player again --> There is no player.currentPosition setter!!!

Comment: BTW: Thanks for your code example. This will definitely help people a lot when wrapping  their heads around the concepts of (the buggy) AVAudioEngine... ;-)

Comment: You are correct, this is a much better way of doing things. When this answer was first created, little was known about the new AVAudioEngine SPI. It was more me taking a crack at it. I will consider rewriting and modernizing it in the furture. Thank you for adding a bit more specificity and truth to my answer